# Apple Mail on iOS 10 loses email message when you switch apps?

Tags: mail.app, messages, ios, multitasking

Can anyone reproduce this behavior?

1. Open the "Messages" app on iOS.
2. Find or create a message that contains an email@address.com.
3. Click the email@address.com to start a new email. (The Apple "Mail" app should open a window on top of the Messages app.)
4. Start typing your message.
5. Suddenly, remember that you have to copy a link from Safari or some other app, so bring up the iOS app switcher by double-clicking the physical home-button.
6. Switch to the other app, copy the link and switch back to your mail message.

Where is your mail message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same behavior I experience following your directions. In addition, the email is not saved as a draft, which would be the expected behavior. Perhaps Apple expects you to start and finish the email without app switching. You should file a [bug report](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) immediately.